# Javascript ImageData: replace "data" field

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, getimagedata

So i have a javascript / html5 page that does some heavy manipulation of images. Because they are heavy, I want to do those in a thread, I extract the image data with getImageData().data to the core. The core then does all the manipulation and sends back the resulting array of pixel information. Now, back in the main thread i want to put the result back to the image, i create a new ImageData object by loading it from the Image with (var imgData = getImageData(...)) and then I want to replace the data in the ImageData Object with the data i got from my 2nd thread. But imgData.data = newData doesnt do anything. Is there a way to do this, other than go through the data array element by element ?

Comment: what you're looking to is is indeed use `putImageData`, that is, you want to copy the data. Nonetheless, could you provide some sample code of what you did, so that we may better assist you?

Comment: There is no sample code needed. I put it in a simple way: I have an ImageData Object and an array of pixel Information. I want to replace the imageData.data Array with my new array. But imageData.data = newData doesnt do anything.

Comment: Threads in JavaScript?…

Comment: Yes, theyre called Web Workers.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign to `imgData.data` directly, you need to use:

```
imgData.data.set(newData)
```

Comment: Are you sure? I can't find this documented anywhere and when I try it Chrome tells me: `Uncaught TypeError: canvasContextImageData.set is not a function`

Comment: I believe you're doing `imgData.set` rather than `imgData.data.set`

Comment: I think you're right! I tried hard to avoid that since I knew the naming was confusing, but was a bit burnt out at the time. I'm indeed using it now and wanted to come back to this thread and say so.

Answer (score -1):

Try: `.putImageData(newData,x,y);`

Comment: newData is an array, not an ImageData Object. You need to have an ImageData Object to put in putImageData()

Answer (score -1):

imageData is a read only property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data)

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you have a context `ctx`:

```
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);
imgData.data = [/*Your array of pixel info*/]
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 100, 100);
```

That should do it.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your array of pixel info?

Comment: Those are very big, way too big to post here, but they are definetly valid. Simply very long arrays of numbers. Edit: actually those are Uint8ClampedArray[]